# Should we have a speed-of-light tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I have seen a few questions relating to or using light speed. These seem to often be tagged with [speed](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) and/or [light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light). I would think the [speed](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) tag would be better categorised as kinematics/motion sort of questions and [light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) lends itself more to questions about the EM spectrum or visible wavelengths. Should we make a [speed-of-light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed-of-light) tag to be used for questions more about relativity/quantum/faster than light travel etc.?

Examples:
[When stars explode why can we still see them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/when-stars-explode-why-can-we-still-see-them)

[Is there an objective difference between space expansion and reduction in speed of light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/is-there-an-objective-difference-between-space-expansion-and-reduction-in-speed)

[Is Darkness Faster Than Light?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12925/is-darkness-faster-than-light)

Comment: Hm, can you show some examples?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's enough of a case yet with just those examples. The second question is the best fit out of those, and it is just tagged with speed, not light; and I think that's appropriate.

Comment: A couple of points:
1) Those were just a few examples, do you want an exhaustive list? 
1) They are all discussing the speed of light as a concept, rather than the speed of anything else or the electromagnetic spectrum. I thought for people who have expertise in particular areas and want to answer questions, it would be useful to separate these concepts so people can easily find questions they know about.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to shoot you down, just trying to make sure I really understand the category of questions we're talking about here. I'm not sure "speed-of-light" is the best name for a tag, and I'm trying to think of ideas; but I need to know the subject area better. If you wouldn't mind, a longer list might be helpful.

Comment: @called2voyage Surprisingly,a "hubble-constant" tag exists, but no other.

Answer (score 3):

I've thought about this some more. How about a more generic [physical-constants](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-constants) tag?

Comment: If someone said "physical constants" to me, I might think of the speed of light, but also things like G (gravitational constant), permittivity of free space, Planck's constant, charge of an electron...
Many things would come under this heading which might not relate to the same kind of questions. However, I think it would be a good compromise, although it should be "constants" not "constant".

Comment: @FJC Right, that's why I said more generic. It would apply to questions of the other constants as well. There is some disagreement over whether tags should be plural or singular, but it does seem like plural would probably be better in this case.

Comment: @FJC And it looks like the tag "physical-constants" already exists for two questions! That is great because it means it is likely to be used.